# package ‘mapdata’ was built under R version 4.0.4

Tags: r

I was trying to make an excercise and I was using "climatol" package but when I tried to install it, two messages appeared and both said that "was built under R version 4.0.4 " in "maps" and "mapdata"... Are they similar packages or how can I update them or what can I do?

Comment: Is updating R an option? Usually you can ignore these messages but updating R is preferable.

Comment: Hi Roland, I tried to update it but it says that I´m using the newest version of RStudio

Comment: Who said anything about updating RStudio? I was talking about R, which is a different software for which RStudio merely provides an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like related packages *maps* and *mapdata* were built under a previous version of R running on your system.

This, and other similar packages, can ideally be corrected by running:

```
update.packages( ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE )
```